# Razor view engine, how to write inbetween html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have some problem with a razor syntax. I would like to know how to write inbetween html.. see this sample..

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var x in Model) {
        <li>
            @x.Subject - Tags:&nbsp;

            @if (x.Tags != null)
            {

                foreach (var t in x.Tags)
                {
                    @t.Name
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                No tags
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I should be able to write "No Tags" but this doesnt work... No tags seem included in the code (which is not what i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to [explicitly tell Razor that you're writing HTML](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx), by writing `@:No Tags` or `<text>No Tags</text>`.

Comment: If you look there : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx is there a reason why with the IF/ELSE statement you don't need the text field ? (goto the section If-Blocks and Multi-line Statements)

Comment: @Rushino: The parser recognizes HTML tags.  You only need this for non-tag-like markup.

Answer (score 3):

Does using the <text> tag work? For example:

```
<text>No tags</text>
```