# Dynamically generate styles inside code block (razor view)

Tags: c#

I create a view call styles.cshtml  where I want to dynamically create stylesheet.
 What is a correct form for css inside code block ?
 Below is wrong code block what is a correct form for this example.

```
 @foreach (var column in Model.Tabs[i].MegaMenuColumns) //columns
 {
        if(column.Width || column.TextColor || column.BackgroundColor)
        {
            #column@(column.Id)
            {
                width: @(column.Width) ;
                color: @(column.TextColor);
                if(column.IsGradient)
                {
                    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                }
                else
                {
                    background: @(column.BackgroundColor);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Razor view engine, how to write inbetween html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952489/razor-view-engine-how-to-write-inbetween-html)

Comment: you could add a <text></text> tag around your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell that from where plain text starts and form where razor code starts.

`@:` tells that it is plain text not razor code and wrting `@` or `@(some code here)` telll that it is c# code block:

```
@foreach (var column in Model.Tabs[i].MegaMenuColumns)
 {
        if(column.Width || column.TextColor || column.BackgroundColor)
        {
            @:#column@(column.Id)
            @:{
                @:width: @(column.Width) ;
                @:color: @(column.TextColor);
                if(column.IsGradient)
                {
                    @:background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    @:background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    @:background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    @:background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                    @:background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, @(column.BackgroundColor) 0%, @(column.BackgroundColorGradient) 100%);
                }
                else
                {
                    @:background: @(column.BackgroundColor);
                }
            @:}
        }
}
```